# Error with setwd in R

Tags: r

When trying to use the sample code for SubgraphMining ([the example is on 35th page](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/slides/pdf/Frequent_Subgraph_Mining.pdf)), I get an error:

```
"Error in setwd(paste(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "library", "subgraphMining",  : 
  cannot change working directory"
```

I'm using RStudio 0.97.551, 32-bit R (2.15.3 - this version of R was recommended to use with subgraphMining), igraph0 (was recommeded too, instead of igraph library), Java installed. Operation system is Windows 8.
Can anyone help me with the issue?

Comment: "cannot change working directory" almost always suggests such a directory doesn't exist. You could debug by just running everything inside the setwd() and check what path it is resolving to.

Comment: As I understand, "R_HOME" is Linux system variable, and I'm using Windows 8. Should I create this system variable on Windows?

Comment: You could. But, can you post your R code to determine what exactly you are trying to do. I looked at the 35th page- it does not have any r-code on it. This is how I normally set the working dir. `setwd(C:\\mydata\\myproject\\)` and then load the packages by calling `library(subgraphMining)`

Comment: Here's the code: 
`graph1 = graph.ring(5);
graph2 = graph.ring(6);
database = array(dim=2);
database[1] = list(graph1);
database[2] = list(graph2);
results = gspan(database, "80%");`
igraph0 and java must be installed, igraph0 and subgraphmining libraries should be on.

Comment: What is this subgraphmining package? It is not on CRAN and bioC and I can't find it anywhere else. Btw. the igraph0 package was removed from CRAN by the CRAN maintainers.

Comment: @GaborCsardi Frequent subgraph mining package may be found there: [Practical Graph Mining with R. CRC Press.](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html). It's a package written for the book. It doesn't work with igraph package, but should work with igraph0 package.

Comment: A noob here, so I do have java installed, but igraph says it's incompatible with R 3.1.2, do I have to install version 2.15 to get subgraphMining package to work? Or should I just work with a more native version of gSpan and subdue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is coming from the `gspan` function of `subgraphMining`, from here:

```
setwd(paste(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "library", "subgraphMining", 
    "parsemis", sep = "\\"))
```

The reason for it is that R uses `/` as path separator, and not `\\`, which only works on windows. A workaround is not modify the function and use `/` instead of `\\`.

Btw. this has nothing to do with the igraph package, so I'll remove that tag.

Comment: I do not use explicetely `\\`` as path separator. Where in the code I have to use (or where in files I have to change) the `/` separator instead of `\\\` separator?

Comment: Not you, the author(s) of the subgraphMining package.

Comment: Would like to add that you can also receive this error if you're just trying to set your wd to a path that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it displayed the error because I expected it to create a new folder which I mentioned in the path in setwd. Unfortunately, R does not have this functionality and the matter was resolved when I created the folder and then used setwd command.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's almost 1 year since this question was posted. I encountered the same problem with subgraphMining package. A quick hack is: You can write "gspan" on RStudio's command line and it will show the function, copy that function and create your own function in your own script (of course with new name, let's say gspanNew) and fix it by replacing "\\" with "/", as [Gabor Csardi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604364/gabor-csardi) pointed out.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use file.path("path","with","code") instead of simple paste in order for your code to be OS independent.